# Cycling using singleton in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I have a singleton class:

```
class SomeManager {
    static let sharedInstance = SomeManager()

    let serverService  = SomerServerService()
    let musicService = SomeMusicService()
}
```

I try to use

```
class SomeMusicService
{
  let serverService = SomeManager.sharedInstance.serverService //here seems I get cycle.
}
```

Should I use lazy or some other initialization.

As you can see `let musicService = SomeMusicService()` initializes an object and then in the same object `SomeMusicService` it tries to call `sharedInstance` of `SomeManager` singleton to get another service at start.

So this is a full listing:

```
import Foundation

class ServerService
{
  func downloadMusic()
  {
    print("Download music and play it after that.")
  }
}

class MusicService
{
  let serverService = Singleton.shared.serverService

  func playMusic()
  {
    serverService.downloadMusic()
  }
}

class Singleton
{
  static let shared = Singleton()

  let serverService = ServerService()
  let musicService = MusicService()
}


let s = Singleton.shared
print("Hello, World!")
```

We never get `print("Hello, World!")` line to be invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `weak` to avoid the retain cycle, but the better answer is a computed property:

```
class SomeMusicService {
    var serverService: SomeService { return SomeManager.sharedInstance.serverService }
}
```

---

I see from your updated code what the cycle is. Here's how it plays out:

- Call Singleton.shared

  - Begin to construct Singleton

    - Construct ServerService (for serverService property)
    - Begin to construct MusicService (for musicService property)

      - Call Singleton.shared (for serverService property)
      - Block waiting for Singleton.shared to complete

The program is now deadlocked waiting on itself.

The right answer is to use a computed property so that there is no need to call `Singleton.shared` during construction. A `lazy` property would work as well, but seems a lot of trouble for this (and risks creating retain loops between the services).

Comment: cool got it, seems in my case singleton still has not been initialized, but I try to use it in the same time. I supposed that there is only lazy option, but seems you're right computed property is also ok.

Comment: I am mean that lazy is guaranties that SomeManager singleton is already created and we can use some properties. And one more question do you think this is retain cycle issue? Maybe I asked in wrong way. seems like I start use the same singleton from one service in another, but I initialize all services in one singleton.

Comment: I've update a question with a listing. Can't understood where we get cycling as I am from Objective-C world =)

Comment: I supposed that lazy guaranties that object was created. So for example I can make all my services in singleton as lazy variables and then they will be available only after singleton is created. By the way thanks for answer!!